# Generic key accessor constrained by type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wanted to write a generic function that returns the value of a boolean property using a type-safe function but ended up with the compiler telling me he don't recognize the type of my value.

```js
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: any
}

function getBooleanValue<T, K extends KeyOfType<T, boolean>>(obj: T, propName: K): boolean {
  return obj[propName]
//         ^
// Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
//   Type 'T[keyof { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends boolean ? P : never]: any; }]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
//     Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
//       Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.(2322)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?ssl=15&ssc=30&pln=15&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAVcEA8KA0UBqAfFALxQDW8A9klAN4BQUUA2gApQCWAduVTSlACGAZygo2AXSgQAHsAhcAJqLxQA-FHYAuKFwgA3CACcJOwVxD0AvvXpIArlwDGwDpR7zhwLLhjS5Csqw8MhokD5QAEaUlAA2EOYEBAAUlJEAVjo4UGBGlGAAcoIAthA6MACUOtFxCTwMTEYQwPZGPGnpzLn5RaUS1ragkJrGwu4kdIy6JWVQXkbcAOZTHMIAsoJGCxCK1THx5gNO7l45Oqyj46S006U6AERF3GCU97irG1scOzpIgrHCCA2TzAZJgXD3D6bbaKe4VKAAegRUHoILBEK4MzhiORxjyRigSG4ECAA)

I would like to avoid casting it to `obj[propName] as unknown as boolean` if possible.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT because lack of context : this operation was done in a generic function

```js
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: any
}

export function compareByBooleanProperty<T, K extends KeyOfType<T, boolean>>(
  propName: K,
): (a: T, b: T) => number {
  const propertyAccessor = (obj: T) => obj[propName]
  const booleanComparator =  compareBooleans
  return (a: T, b: T) => {
    const aValue = propertyAccessor(a)
    const bValue = propertyAccessor(b)
    return booleanComparator(aValue, bValue)
//                            ^
// Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
//   Type 'T[keyof { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends boolean ? P : never]: any; }]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
//     Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
//       Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.(2322)
  }
}

function compareBooleans(a: boolean, b: boolean): number {
  // algorithm
  return 0
}


type Person = {
  name: string
  isMarried: boolean
}

compareByBooleanProperty<Person, "isMarried">("isMarried") // comparator function by
```

[New playground version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAVcEA8KA0UBqAfFALxQDW8A9klAN4BQUUA2gApQCWAduVTSlACGAZygo2AXSgQAHsAhcAJqLxQA-FHYAuKFwgA3CACcJOwVxD0AvvXqywlI8ChIArlwDGwDpR4fKALZggkYQAEIgYZSUADYQ5qxGlJBOIFi4MNJyCsqw8MhokOlQAEbRceYEBAAUjFBgSWAAcoIBEDow2PQAlDrVgjo4pYPdJERcrgElxnR1-lzCzg3JxqAAgh4eEMLCjiRQ1ZQlAFYjY1BHx8zLza0QEnO%20i6Xl8VwAwoHBRoLAe6RQfxBELhV7mYR1ULAVxGHj9Qa4EpnYhEBhMJjzZ6CPCCGKuaCkG6rEAbLY7Rz9bp1DFPZwlHF4gn1RrE0nbXZGaolKnoqBQmE8MqxN6fYE-P6c7G4-GIhn4nlQGw2ehuTzeXyAr4gqLC8Hwl66riInRCipcXq6SbTIyzJgAejtQhiAHNHBxgAALAKQiDQ2FQAAM1ls9FAkE0xl2PFIaN0dx0iyM3GddQ4wgAsiEkxBFCawVxg-Qgd9wpF84kVqkMKxI75cAAiNOZozZxT1mqNjNZjg5%20ujB2asW-Paqrw%20QUgKBAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLv2ew) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer  explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler won't infer `T[K]` to be boolean if you just filter out `K`; that's why you should also type the `T`; in our case, `T extends Record<K, boolean>` would be enough, since we don't care about the other keys, we only care that `T[K]` must be boolean.

```
export function compareByBooleanProperty<
  T extends Record<K, boolean>,
  K extends KeyOfType<T, boolean>,
>(propName: K): (a: T, b: T) => number {
// ...
}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj816m)

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of your function to `T[K]` instead of `boolean`:

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: any;
}

function test<T, K extends KeyOfType<T, boolean>>(obj: T, propName: K): T[K] {
  return obj[propName];
}

type X = KeyOfType<Person, boolean>

type Person = {
  name: string;
  isMarried: boolean;
}
const p: Person = { name: "Nainpo", isMarried: false };
test(p, "isMarried");
test(p, "name");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAVcEA8KA0UBqAfFALxQDW8A9klAN4BQUUA2gApQCWAduVTSlACGAZygo2AXSgQAHsAhcAJqLxQA-FHYAuKFwgA3CACcJOwVxABuegF969JAFcuAY2AdKPecOBZcMaTkFZVh4ZDRIPygAI0pKABsIcwICAApKaIArHRwoMCNKMAA5QQBbCB0YAEoc5hgpBiYjCGBHIx4MzOZ8wpLyiWs7elBIKAANElDEVHQMVmNhT1xYhKSuAnsR6HmjRZ5SRt0yiqgfI24Ac2smDmEAWUEjc4hFHRXE80H6F08fPJ0dntJrQjuUdAAiErcMCUcG4W4PJ4cF46JCCeLCaA2azeYCpMC4cEIx7PRTgqo4iA+fGErjHcmWIA)

Comment: Oh. I simplified too much my example. I need to call a function that accepts a boolean arg in my generic function `test` 

I updated my question by adding a new playground link (don't know if it's the right way to do it sry).

Comment: @Nainpo does this work for you? [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj816m)

Comment: Yes, it's the right way to do it! I will accept it as the answer, for the initial lack of context.